# How to upload and display images on Ruby on Rails without storing them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm making a demo for a ruby gem I created that process images and I have my application for the demo using the gem. I want the demo to allow the user to upload an image and try the demo but I don't really want to store the image in a database.

I read about redis but I'm not sure if is the right solution since I don't think is intended to be used with images.

Comment: Why not store the images? If you're worried about storage usage, you can have a periodic workers that cleans up old uploads.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could simply ask the user to upload an image address as a string rather than a file?

Answer (score 0):

Storing in Redis is not a bad idea, you could also set an expiry date to delete keys older than x days / hours. But keep in mind that Redis is still a database which you need to maintain.

Another approach is to just store it on the filesystem and delete the oldest file before storing a new one so you only store the latest x files.

http://qnimate.com/storing-binary-data-in-redis/

> maybe you could simply ask the user to upload an image address as a string rather than a file?

I like this approach by Hassan, you could ask the user to upload to Dropbox / Google files for instance. Or ask to enter the email address and use Gravatar. This would be a light weight approach so if it's just an example I would go for this.